# How can the u= parameter be removed from from search query strings?

Tags: 2010, search, sharepoint-foundation

I have a top-level team site at `http://sharepoint` and an enterprise search center site at `http://sharepoint/sites/search`. There is an alternative access mapping for the web application - sharepoint.int.company.com.

I'm finding that using the normal search field of the team site results in the site sending the user to `http://sharepoint/sites/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=marketing&cs=This%20Site&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsharepoint`. This page doesn't return any results. If I manually change the URL so that 'u=sharepoint', or the 'u' parameter is completely removed, and I refresh the page, then the search page returns results.

How can I update the team site so that is doesn't pass the 'u' parameter across to the search center?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure the search box from the Site Collection > Site Settings > Search Settings page. Enable *Custom Scopes* and select the dropdown mode *Do not show scopes dropdown, and default to target results page*. These settings are, however, only available with SharePoint Server search features enabled on the site collection.

Answer (score -1):

If *sharepoint* the name of your application pool you could try to add the url to access mappings.